# Error using bootstrap's pagination navigation links

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display pagination for a page(`home.php`) that displays the results of a search done on a form(`index.php`). The problem is that the navigation link on the pagination code does not direct to the next page, it instead directs to an empty page (I believe the normal state of `home.php`) even when the URL at the address reads `home.php?page=2`.

index.php

```
<form action='home.php' action='post'>
//Form elements
</form>
```

home.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Display search results

//Shows pagination
$page_count2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM offers WHERE school = :school"; 
$rs_result =  $db-> query($page_count2, array('school' => $_POST['school'])); 
$row = $rs_result->fetch(); 
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 6); 

echo "
<div class='row text-center'>
<ul class='pagination  pag'>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 

    if ($page == $i)
           echo "<li class='active' >";
    else
           echo "<li>";

    echo "<a href='home.php?page=$i' >$i</a></li>";
};
echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

Comment: you are using a `$_POST` variable for `school` which will not carry over from page to page

Comment: @cmorrissey how do I solve this problem now?

Comment: use `$_GET` and appended it to your pagination

Comment: @cmorrissey I don't know how to append to the pagination. I have changed to $_GET.